# Get values based on all matched content xsl

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have following xml :

```
        <main>
          <text>
           <naresh:parentText>
             <naresh:text type="anotheroption"></naresh:text>   
             <naresh:text type="MyCustom1"></naresh:text>
             <naresh:text type="MyCustom2"></naresh:text>
             <naresh:text type="MyCustom3"></naresh:text>
             <naresh:text type="MyCustom4"></naresh:text>
           </ns1:parentText>
        </text>

     </main>
```

I am trying to display the data using below xslt but no luck:

```
       <xsl:for-each select="main/text/naresh:parentText/naresh:text[starts-with(@type, 'MyCustom')]">  
          <xsl:call-template name="myTemplate"></xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:template name = "myTemplate">    

        <xsl:value-of select="."  disable-output-escaping="yes"   />

     </xsl:template>
```

Can any please help me out?

Thanks,
Naresh.

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete sample of XML input, XSLT code, output you want and output you get, to allow us to easily reproduce the problem. Posting a snippet where the root element is `Text` but then showing an XSLT snippet where the path starts with `main/text` does not make sense, you have not shown a `main` element and the element you have shown is called `Text` with capital `T` and not `text`. Nor do I see any `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

XML:

```
<Text xmlns:naresh="www.my.web">
<naresh:parentText>
    <naresh:text type="anotheroption"></naresh:text>
    <naresh:text type="MyCustom1"></naresh:text>
    <naresh:text type="MyCustom2"></naresh:text>
    <naresh:text type="MyCustom3"></naresh:text>
    <naresh:text type="MyCustom4"></naresh:text>
</naresh:parentText>
</Text>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:naresh="www.my.web">

<xsl:template match="Text">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[starts-with(@type, 'MyCustom')]">    
        <xsl:call-template name="myTemplate"></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name = "myTemplate">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@type" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
MyCustom1
MyCustom2
MyCustom3
MyCustom4
```

Note: While posting, please place the simple and complete XSLT code including stylesheet header or root and required result also.